# Infragistics license exceptions when MSBuild-ing

Tags: exception, msbuild, infragistics

When running the MSBuild scripts for a project, I'm getting the following errors:

```
Properties\licenses.licx(1): error LC0004: Exception occurred creating type 'Infragistics.Win.UltraWinEditors.UltraNumericEditor, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinEditors.v5.2, Version=5.2.20052.1028, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb' System.ComponentModel.LicenseException: Unable to locate license assembly.
Properties\licenses.licx(2): error LC0004: Exception occurred creating type 'Infragistics.Win.Misc.UltraGridBagLayoutManager, Infragistics.Win.Misc.v5.2, Version=5.2.20052.1028, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb' System.ComponentModel.LicenseException: Unable to locate license assembly.
Properties\licenses.licx(3): error LC0004: Exception occurred creating type 'Infragistics.Win.UltraWinEditors.UltraCheckEditor, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinEditors.v5.2, Version=5.2.20052.1028, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb' System.ComponentModel.LicenseException: Unable to locate license assembly.
```

It appears that there's a problem with my machine's Infragistics license.

I have valid license files in my solution, so what's causing this issue?

Comment: When you build with MSBuild, are you using the same .csproj/.sln files or custome ones? Is this on the same computer as when you build from Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm not building from Visual Studio at the moment, since the development process here is to use MSBuild. But yes, all the files are on my machine and it's building the same project/solution files.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From a user comment in [Infragistics forum archive](http://forums.archive.infragistics.com/readmessage?id=%3C341d53df$77bdd6fe$1bff@news.infragistics.com%3E&group=infragistics.products.netadvantage.windowsforms.deployment&ei=ZShqS7PSKIrW8AbI5qy9Bw&usg=AFQjCNEyGw_lLWbf2xxAWroWet-f1Hwmug&sig2=M63m2-2Wq12z7goKYLqniw)

> install as the Sysadmin for "All Users" and then the 
>   user will develop and compile their app.

Here is a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071459/infragistics-components-on-build-server/2092427#2092427) but unfortunately, this does not explain the root cause.

Here is a [blog post from Infragistics](http://blogs.infragistics.com/blogs/ed_blankenship/archive/2007/07/16/building-apps-using-netadvantage-with-team-build.aspx) to deal with automated builds but I don't think it is your case. And a further reference to that same post adding more info [here](http://blogs.infragistics.com/forums/p/12859/47668.aspx).

I guess you had already looked at those links but they might be helpful to somebody else with a similar problem.

Answer (score 46):

There is a much easier solution: Set the build action on your license.licx to None.

Comment: It works like a charm but then you have to remember to install the license in the client. Anyway, it works!! Thank you a tons

Comment: Works perfectly... Thanks :)

Comment: How does one set the build action?

Answer (score 2):

it's much easier just to only change the build compilation to any CPU and you're done!
it will run with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the license compiler (lc.exe) can find the location of your Infragistics assemblies. Also, if you've updated your components anytime recently make sure there aren't multiple copies with different version numbers lying around. Finally make sure that the version your are trying to use is the same version in the licenses.licx file.

An easy way to refresh the licenses.licx is it open the form designer, add an Infragistics component and remove it.

If for some reason the licenses.licx file doesn't refresh you can try removing the offending entries first then refresh it.

Answer (score 0):

It was possible to solve the problem by clearing out the content of the files every time it is found in a repository.

For example, in a batch file in the DevOps pipeline, after getting the latest source code, this script empties the content of the files.

```
:: CD current_project_dir

:: reset licenses.licx files
:: reference: https://github.com/augustoproiete/EmptyLicensesLicx
for /f %%a in ('dir licenses.licx /s /B') do (  
    type nul > %%a
)
```

As mentioned in the reference site, the `licenses.licx` is not needed during the build step, only needed during the development/IDE phase.